# why BernoulliNB classifier returning same value for all data set?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ipython

I tried using BernoulliNB to predict iris data set. But the trained model returns some random value as prediction for all test data set. I tried the same data set with decision tree where the trained model predicted the test data set with good accuracy.

```
import pandas as pn
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as lk

def labelmod(x):
    if(x =='Iris-versicolor'):
        return 0
    elif(x =='Iris-setosa'):
        return 1
    elif(x =='Iris-virginica'):
        return 3
    else:
        return

def celldif(x):
    return x.apply(labelmod)

ok = pn.read_csv(r"C:\Users\s420105\Desktop\iris.csv",header = None)
data=ok.dropna()
labels = data.ix[:,4:]
labels=labels.apply(celldif)
data=data.ix[:,0:3]
train_data,test_data,train_label,test_label=lk(data,labels,test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB 
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(train_data,train_label.values.ravel())
result= classifier.predict(test_data)
result
```

the result returns
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64) as output

The test and train labels are fine. For decision tree i passed the train_label without including values.ravel()

Comment: Does it matter? I mean when comparing with test_label, do you get poor accuracy? And have you tried multiple runs of the code or just one time?

Comment: its not even close comparing to test_label. I have done multiple runs by converting the train_data to array which causes the result to become array of value 1 for all test data set.

Comment: Have you tried any other estimator? Maybe BernoulliNB is not suitable for this task!!

Comment: Yes I did try Decision tree and it gives a very good prediction with very good accuracy. But I am not sure BernoulliNB giving wrong value. I doubt if this is due to passing the data set as array using ravel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is scale the data before `BernoulliNB`. I'm using iris dataset from `scikit-learn` because I don't have your CSV. But this is not a problem with `ravel()`, it's a data scaling problem.

```
import pandas as pn
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as lk
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = datasets.load_iris().data
labels = datasets.load_iris().target

data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

train_data,test_data,train_label,test_label=lk(data,labels,test_size=0.3)
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(train_data,train_label)
result= classifier.predict(test_data)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks.Scaling solves the problem, but BernoulliNB has bad accuracy comparing to decision tree on this data set.

Comment: Yep. That's possible. Not all algorithms will perform well for every type of problem :=)